# new programmer adb connection error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I keep running into an ADB error when opening Eclipse.  I receive it continuously every 10-20 seconds:

```
[2011-08-24 21:25:40 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2011-08-24 21:25:41 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
```

In the task manager processes is a continuous process of ADB running and a second instance appears and vanishes at the same rate as the error broadcasts above.

I've reinstalled both Eclipse and the Android SDK and have attempted to kill ADB via the command line, but it did not help.  Any tips would be appreciated, and as I am new to Android and Eclipse, speaking loudly and slowly would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jansen, welcome to Stackoverflow! Is there a device (phone or tablet) attached to your computer when the error occurs?

Comment: no usually i have everything unplugged and my emulator is not running and thanks for the welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is going on but try the following and see if it helps:

- close eclipse
- run the command "adb kill-server"
- kill all running instances of the adb process
- restart eclipse

If this doesn't work try running the command "adb devices". Any error messages here?

Comment: Thanks THelper you were a big help.  I actually ended up figuring out that it was my asus sync, the program that handles all syncing between my pc and my eeepad transformer, causing the issue.  It by default starts up in the background and i dont know if it sets up some sort of virtual drive for connectivity or something but it was throwing my eclipse for a loop.  Anyway once i exited it it stopped being silly and now works great.  Thanks for the response

Comment: I am pretty sure it connect to the transformer using adb as well... or at least adb on the phone with some other usb based connection.

Answer (score 0):

As THelper replied you might have connected to device or already a dead emulator might be opened

Comment: no usually i have everything unplugged and my emulator is not running