# Error connection with android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

My application work fine on my emulator but when i installed it in the android device its not appear on the application list and i get the error message is "error connection" this is the manifest.xml to my app is there any error!!!!

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.starting"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_starting" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_starting" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.StartingActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It's seems that your device is not recognized by ADB, have you installed the drivers? If you try to launch "adb devices" does it returns your phone? Which phone are you using?

Comment: alternatively you can copy your apk to sd card and try to install on your device.

Comment: using galagcy s3 but i tried to run it on many devices and tried to copy the apk file to the device but i faced the same problem

Comment: This is not a problem with your code (and so pasting it won't help). It's a problem with the setup and with Eclipse's recognition of your device. Try some of the [following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184861/new-programmer-adb-connection-error-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Hey its not the issue with code i guess. Please turn on USB debugging in your phone and the try.